# Succinct way to create array of pointers to anonymous objects

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an array of pointers to anonymous objects, something like:

```
Level* levels[] {&Level1(), &Level2(), &Level3()};
```

where Level is a parent class to Level1, Level2, and Level3. Unfortunately, this fails compilation. Instead, it seems I am forced to do this:

```
Level1 level1;
Level2 level2;
Level3 level3;
Level* levels[]{&level1, &level2, &level3};
```

Is their a way to write this without first declaring each object?

Comment: `Level* levels[]{new Level1, new Level2, new Level3};`?

Comment: @MikeCAT I wouldn't recommend using `new` manually. If any of those `new`s throws (except the first one), you'll get a memory leak, and there's no way to fix.

Comment: Do you really need pointers?  Most of the time you don't.  `std::vector<Level> levels(3);` will give you 3 `Level`'s in a container.

Comment: There's no way that doesn't involve dynamic allocation, no. You can't create objects with automatic storage *and* a lifetime that extends beyond the full-expression where they were created without naming them.

Comment: @molbdnilo You could create a class with two members: a tuple and and an array of pointers to its elements.

Comment: @molbdnilo sounds like an answer!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It might not even be necessary to materialize that second array; you can have a class method which generates the array on demand. Depends on the intended use, of course.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The problem with `vector<Base>(3)` is that it would slice any `Derived1`, `Derived2` or `Derived3` that you would try to insert. The goal here is to have a heterogeneous collection of related objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of the comments. @MSalters is correct that I want an array of heterogeneous but related objects, not an array of "Base" objects. In the end, it looks like I either need to use dynamic allocation or live with declaring the objects first. Thank you to @molbdnilo for the clarity in your answer and to @HolyBlackCat for the creative thoughts and the warning about using dynamic allocation. Much appreciated.